# python appending lists, saving as text, and losing "\t"format

Tags: python, string, list, append

I have code now that after every for loop iteration appends a line of results to a list. Results correspond with people (lets say "Bill") and Bill ends up with a list (statsG) of size 3 with his results. I use np.reshape (gives string624 of size (1,3)) so that when I save statsG to a txt file it is one line (Bill 1 2 3 4). 
Now this is within a larger for loop that iterates through all the patients (lets say "Bill","Jane", "Susan"). So I want to append each patient's info to some form that I can then save to a readable text file (Bill 1 2 3 4
 Susan 1 5 2 6
 Jane 5 2 6 7)

The code now (which I've tried writing 50 different way) gives me a great looking statsG file, but the GlobalStats file has each line bracketed [['text']] and the tabs ("\t") stay as \t  [['blahblah\tblahblah]].
I'm changing type a lot so I'm sure thats screwing something up. Thoughts?

```
  statsG.append(str(diameter_Glob[1]-diameter_Glob[0])+"\t"+str(100*(diameter_Glob[1]-diameter_Glob[0])/diameter_Glob[1])+"\t"+str(pval[1]))
    statsG2=np.reshape(statsG,(1,3))

    np.savetxt(path+'Stats.txt',statsG2,'%s')
    GlobalStats.append(str(start)+"\t"+str(stop)+"\t"+str(statsG2))
np.savetxt('/Volumes/old/RESULTS.txt',GlobalStats, '%s')
```

the

Comment: I looks like the the text you want is a list in a list, try extracting that text before casting it as a str

Answer (score 1):

To turn a list into a string, don't just use `str(mylist)`, that's responsible for adding the brackets and turning your tab characters into `\t`. Instead use `join`, e.g. to put a tab between each string in the list: `'\t'.join(mylist)`.

Comment: But the line for each person (each statsG) is composed of floats and strings so don't i need to convert the floats to strings to concatenate?

Comment: @user3470496 yes, you'll need to convert the floats to strings. You probably want to do that as a separate step anyway so you have more control over it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `'\t'.join(list)` instead of `str(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are getting `[['text']]` because you are turning a nested list into a string so instead of doing `str(variable)` actually reference the variable like `variable[0][0]` (may need to be changed a bit to actually get the value). As for the `\t` try changing the `"\t"` to `'\t'` making it a char instead of a string (don't know if it will work but worth trying).

Comment: In Python there's no difference between a char and a string.

Comment: I know but for some reason doing so has worked in the past. Just thought I would mention it.